# BAT file Windows Parse if first filename character is digit

Tags: batch-file

Hy,

i am normally using linux and i would get the problem solved there.
For work i have to do a batch  script that automatically merges pdf files. it works, but i want a defined structure: The first digit of the file names
defines the order (1-5).
First all documents (word, xls... etc)  get converted in a pdf. then these pdfs are merged according 1-5. Actually all pdfs are merged, 1-5 and then the rest. I thin an if statement will solve it, but how to check if the first Character is a digit?
for example: if (first charcter = digit) {convert}

```
rem MSWord Documents
rem MAKES WORD TO PDF
set docxs=
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /on /b *.docx') do set docxs=!docxs! "%%f"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDF24\pdf24-doctool.exe" -shellPrint –printerName "PDF24" -applyProfile -profile "default/best" -outputDir %CD% %docxs% 

rem merge pdf messages
rem THIS WILL MERGE all pdfs 1-5 HERE THE IF STATEMENT NEEDS TO BE
set pdfs=
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /on /b *.pdf') do set pdfs=!pdfs! "%%f"
pdftk %pdfs% cat output EINGANGSRECHNUNGMITBANF.pdf
```

no output, just not working

Comment: Just call a label that tests the first character of a variable against a set of numbers.. for instance. `set str=3ABC` and then `@for %%i in (12345) do if %str:~0,1% equ %%i @echo It's a number`

Comment: `...in ('dir /on /b *.pdf ^|findstr /b [0-9]') do ...` filters the output of the `dir` command to those who start with a number.

Comment: wait - I disagree with your logic: `dir /on` will sort yor files by name - which means numbers come before letters. It should already sort correctly (starting with `1...` to `9...`, then `A..`, `B..` etc.